# Сброс значения в postgresql

Tags: postgresql, база-данных

Нужно установить счетчику нужное мне значение, а то он пытается пихнуть данные в уже существующие значения.
Нашел несколько вариантов как сбросить значения, или установить нужное:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE serial RESTART WITH 105;
```

и

```
SELECT setval('sysusers_id_seq', (select max(id)+1 from sysusers) +1);
```

Но беда, вообще не могу понять что нужно ставить вместо **serial** или **sysusers_id_seq**.

Пихал туда поле id, пихал и название_таблицы.id, везде ошибка, примеров живых в Иете не нашел. В мануалах везде коротко - "поле содержащее счетчик".

Расшифруйте пожалуйста, или на примере покажите.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Название sequence.

Когда создаете колонку со столбцом [типа `SERIAL`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) (или `BIGSERIAL`), то это под капотом то же самое, что и создание sequence с именем «*имятаблицы*`_`*имястолбца*`_seq`» с определением a-la `colname integer DEFAULT nextval('tablename_colname_seq') NOT NULL`.

Т.е.:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE dummy (id SERIAL, foo INTEGER);
ALTER SEQUENCE dummy_id_seq RESTART WITH 100;
INSERT INTO dummy (foo) VALUES (1);
SELECT * FROM dummy -- Вернет [(id=100, foo=1)]
```

Comment: хм, то есть в моем случае если таблица - tab, поле - id, то нужно указать tab_id_seq?

Comment: Да, если создавали как `CREATE TABLE tab (id SERIAL, ...)` — совершенно верно, `tab_id_seq`.

Comment: Не, создавалась таблица автоматически (программно), не могу гарантировать что именно как вы сказали.

Comment: Откройте pgAdmin3 и посмотрите на таблицу, он все покажет :) Или в psql используйте команду `\d tab`.

Там будет описание колонки `id` какого-то такого вида: `... not null default nextval('tab_id_seq'::regclass)`. Вот имя в `nextval()` — это то, что надо.

Comment: @drdaeman спасибо, посмотрел через navicat. действительно так и есть.

Спасибо, всё вышло.